# How to convert the following string to date string again?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string passed from kendo grid filter as follows,

**`2018-05-01T18:30:00.000Z`**

i need to conver the above to this format,

```
May 05 2018
```

i tried with the following,

```
string  date = (DateTime.ParseExact(constant.ToString(), "MMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToString("MMM dd yyyy");
```

bit its not working as expected

Comment: `ParseExact` requires that the input match the specified format exactly. How could you possibly think that '2018-05-01T18:30:00.000Z" exactly matches the format "MMM dd yyyy"? I suggest that you do some more reading on date formats and determine what format the `String` you have is actually in.

Comment: What's up with this: `constant.ToString()`? What is `constant`? What data type is it? If it's a `String` then why are you calling `ToString` on it? If it's a `DateTime` then why are you converting it to a `String` and then to a `DateTime` and then to a `String` when you could just convert it directly to a `String` in the desired format?

Comment: const is string 2018-05-01T18:30:00.000Z

Comment: "const is string". In that case, the first `ToString` call is pointless.  You never need to convert a `String` to a `String`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i need to convert to that specific format

Comment: or is there anywa to convert 2018-05-01T18:30:00.000Z to "May 05 2018"

Comment: I know you need to convert that specific format. I've told you what you should do. If you refuse to do it then that's on you. This site is not supposed to be a substitute for thought and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the call to `DateTime.ParseExact` is not the format of the date that you're passing. You could change the format, or call DateTime.Parse directly as that format is recognized by it:

```
String dateString = "2018-05-01T18:30:00.000Z";

DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
DateTime date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ", null);

Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("MMM dd yyyy"));
Console.WriteLine(date2.ToString("MMM dd yyyy"));
```

Comment: How is it not working? I just tried it locally and it does work.

Comment: Please refer to my updated answer including both working examples.

Comment: date and date2 are strings in my case

Comment: Ok. See my updated answer. Does it make more sense to you now?

Comment: Message: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Can you post the string that you're passing to the `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact` functions?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `DateTime.Parse(dateString)` (considering its an ISO-8601 string)?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the following.  And please note that the datetime string actually represents May 1 2018, not May 5 2018 as mentioned in the question.

```
var d = DateTime.Parse("2018-05-01T18:30:00.000Z");

Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("MMM dd yyyy"));
```